# What languages are /usr/bin files written in Mac, and how can I read their code?

Tags: shell, macintosh

In /usr/bin/ on Mac, there are files such as csrutil. What languages are these written in and how can I read their code? Converting it to shell script didn't work out for me as I only got gibberish with portions of readable text. Does anyone know how to read these files as they don't have any suffix i'm not sure what to do.

Comment: They are written in [x86 machine code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_instruction_listings#Original_8086/8088_instructions); on the other hand, what do you actually want to do?

Comment: They are written in what ever language they want to be written in. The interpreted ones, you can read. The others will be compiled from source code. This may or may not be available. If you want to be guaranteed access to the source code, then you need to run Free Software. Free Software respects your freedom. It gives you the freedom to run, study, modify, distribute the code for any reason and for any price.

Comment: Suffixes on an executable is a bad bad idea. What happens when you re-write your shell script in python, and then in C or purl. Would you change the filename, and therefore edit all code that references it. File suffixes are a bad idea for all files, but much worse for executable (May be we could have had a suffix for all pictures (.gif, .jpeg, .tiff, .png, etc would all be .picture). To find out the type of a file, you must look into it. Use `file «filename»`. Though this will most likely lead to you realising that you need the source code to be able to understand the program.

Comment: If you can not get hold of the source code, then have a look at the work of the GNU project, they have re-written the Unix tools, and you are free to view the source code, and even make changes, to your own copy. And to offer these changed versions to others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are meant to be read by your Mac, not by you.  There may be scripts among them, but most of them are executables, "machine code", eg. written in C but then compiled and linked.  The program "file" will allow you to check the contents, if you get an answer containing "text", you can have a look, otherwise it's quite useless.

Answer (score 4):

As Gerard H. Pille already said, those files are executables, designed to be read by the OS and the processor directly. Technically, the name of the file format is [Mach-O, or Mach object file format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mach-O).

With the `strings` command, you can view any uncompressed text strings within an executable. If you need to identify an unknown executable file, this is sometimes useful. For example: `strings /usr/bin/csrutil | less`

Technically, it is possible to translate the machine code back to a more human-readable form. This is called *disassembling* an executable, and the result would be in *assembly language* specific to each processor architecture: for example, the assembly language of modern Macs based on 64-bit Intel x86 processors would be different from the assembly language of old PowerMacs that used Motorola's PowerPC processors.

You could also use a *debugger* utility, ideally with the [debug symbols file](https://lldb.llvm.org/symbols.html) matching the executable you're debugging, to monitor the internal workings of a running executable. Or if you have a problem that causes an program to crash, you could enable *core dumps* and then use a debugger to analyze the core dump file resulting from the crash of a program.

Reading the assembly language is nothing like reading a shell script: it requires a lot more understanding of the technical details of the processor and the operating system. Even a simple operation, like outputting some text, requires a number of assembly language instructions to locate the memory address of the text to be displayed and then call the appropriate operating system function that actually does the job.

However, there is a legal caveat: depending on your local legislation, you may have agreed to not disassemble any operating system executables (if the legalese you had to click through when installing the OS is enforceable) - and copyright law will definitely restrict the use of information gained from such disassembly.

Since the macOS operating system is proprietary and not open source, you probably would have to be employed by Apple (or at least have a very good reason and have signed an appropriate NDA) to have a chance to get to see the actual source code that produced any published version of macOS.